# How to add buddy/user in group in xmpp iphone?

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I have wrote this code for creating room. Using this i had created room in openfire.

```
-(void)createGroup:(NSString*)groupName
{
      XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *rosterstorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];            
      xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.%@/%@",groupName,@"server",self.strUsername]] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

      [xmppRoom activate:[self xmppStream]];
      [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"nickname" history:nil];
      [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
      [self performSelector:@selector(ConfigureNewRoom) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];   
}
-(void)ConfigureNewRoom
{
    [xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
    [xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
}
```

Now I want to add buddy/users in the group. so how can i do this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Using this it is done

```
    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
    NSString *strJid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.%@/%@",groupname,strHostname,self.strUsername];
    self.xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:strJid] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [self.xmppRoom activate:self.xmppStream];
    [self.xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:self.strUsername history:nil];

    //inviting
    NSString *strInvitedUserName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",personName,strHostname];
    [self.xmppRoom inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:strInvitedUserName] withMessage:message];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add it to your roster in this way:

```
[[[self appDelegate] xmppRoster] addUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"userName"] withNickname:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] groups:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"general", nil]];
```

and check it:

```
XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage *xmppRosterStorage = [[self appDelegate] xmppRosterStorage];
BOOL knownUser = [xmppRosterStorage userExistsWithJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"userName"] xmppStream:[self xmppStream]];
```

Comment: Hi Hayro, Hardik is asking about adding a member in a chat room. Your answer explains about adding a buddy to buddy list but doesn't explain how to add it in a chat room.